# What is the command to return to your main screen in an app?

Tags: android, command, homescreen

How do I have an app return to the 'Home' screen when the user is on a different class and they click the back/return button on their phone?

Right now, when they access a different class and hit the back button, it goes back to the Home screen on the Droid rather than the Home screen on the app - how do I get it to go back to the Home Screen on the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OnBackPressed() method of Activity class.
Make conditions like :

```
public void onBackPressed(){    
if(conditon)
  {
    detailInfoList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//or anything that you want to show
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't,

the home button is the only you can't prevent form closing your app. Its done so that you can't block the user inside your applications (like a virus).

the other keys like back menu and research are possible

in your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(keyCode == 82){
               Log.i("jason","released on menu");
               //change view
               //return so that the other behavior (leaving the activity) is not tirggered
               return false;
        }   
        }
        Log.i("jason","actual key code "+keyCode);
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: ahhh, well what if I use the back/return button?  For instance, if I am displaying a result.xml file to the user, and if they press the back/return button it takes them back to the app's home screen rather than the droid's home screen?

Comment: I change the code a bit, what you want is to catch the key, change the view and then not call the super to avoid exiting the application. I use back to go back one screen and menu to go back the the main menu in my app